# Is there a list of the most prominent textbooks in each field of medical expertise?

Tags: obstetrics, psychiatrist-psychiatry

I am familiar with Harrison's principles of internal medicine and Nelson's textbook of pediatrics, which I've heard are regarded as the go-to books in their respective fields.

I am looking for more books of the same level in other medical fields (especially psychiatry and obstetrics), so I was wondering if there was anywhere a list of the best textbooks for each medical expertise?

Comment: Are you getting the e-versions? Are you a medical student? Or just a very interested self-taught layperson? Because textbooks are very expensive and become outdated quickly. A disease is a disease is a disease until genetics, microbiology and technology took a giant leap into the picture. Now things change almost daily. Also, people have their favorites. I bought the two-volume Cecil's over Harrison's.

Comment: I am not a med student, I'm a pharmacist looking to improve his medical knowledge. I know that the books are expensive, but I intend to look for them online or at libraries, I just need to know what to look for. No doubt that people will have their preferences, I'm looking for the general trend. Having more than one option for each field is only welcome...

Comment: Then have at it (I really admire the ambition, and think it will pay off greatly.) Great question! Though it's a list-type question, I'll see what I can do, or you can post about it in meta and see if it's allowed.

Comment: Thanks! I am aware that this is a list question which is not the type of questions covered here; that's why I asked if there is a list, not for the list itself... ;-) If people would care to share their favorites in the comments, that's fine too...

Comment: requesting off site links is off topic.